# Каким способом можно достучаться к закрытым переменным

Tags: c#, ооп

Суть задания создать класс трапеции которая задана на координатной , найти ее стороны и тд. Создал класс "trapezoid" и "point" который имеет точки х , у , но они по заданию должны быть закрытыми как в данной ситуации можно с класса трапеции использовать переменные "х" и "у"(конструкторами пользоваться разрешено)

Класс точки (х , у)

```
 public class Point
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
}
```

класс трапеции

```
 public class Trapezoid
{


    public Point A = new Point();
    public Point B = new Point();
    public Point C = new Point(); 
    public Point D = new Point();
    public Point H = new Point();




    public double GetAB() {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B.x - A.x, 2) + Math.Pow(B.y - A.y, 2));
    }
    public double GetBC() {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(C.x - B.x, 2) + Math.Pow(C.y - B.y, 2));
    }
    public double GetCD() {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(D.x - C.x, 2) + Math.Pow(D.y - C.y, 2));
    }
    public double GetDA() {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(A.x - D.x, 2) + Math.Pow(A.y - D.y, 2));
    }
    public double GetBH() {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B.x - H.x, 2) + Math.Pow(B.y - B.y, 2));
    }

    public double Area() {
        return ((GetAB() + GetDA()) / 2) * GetBH();
    }

    public double Perimeter() {
        return ((GetAB() + GetDA() + GetBC() + GetCD()));

    }
}
```

Comment: не надо достукиваться. надо просто добавить метод в класс  Point. внутри этого метода переменные этого класса доступны

Comment: Заодно и куча копипасты GetA...H уйдёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C# можно реализовать аналог "дружественного" класса из C++ следующим [способом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507130/7388307)

```
using System;

partial class Point
{
    private Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    int x;
    int y;

    public static Point NewPoint(int x,int y)
    {
        return new Point(x,y);
    } 
}

partial class Point
{
    public class Rectangle
    {
        public Rectangle(Point A, Point B, Point C,Point D)
        {
            this.A=A;
            this.B=B;
            this.C=C;
            this.D=D;
        }

        Point A;
        Point B;
        Point C;
        Point D;

        public void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Point A: {0},{1}",A.x,A.y);
            Console.WriteLine("Point B: {0},{1}",B.x,B.y);
            Console.WriteLine("Point C: {0},{1}",C.x,C.y);
            Console.WriteLine("Point D: {0},{1}",D.x,D.y);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Point.Rectangle(Point.NewPoint(0,0),Point.NewPoint(0,1),Point.NewPoint(1,0),Point.NewPoint(1,1)).Draw();    
    }
}
```

Чекнуть можно [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8DSm8G)

Comment: Если вы можете ответить на вопрос, ответьте. Ссылку на более подробное изложение сути дела можете добавить, но ответ не должен только из .

Comment: Это хак: по смыслу трапеция не является вложенным объектом точки. Правильным решением было бы дать доступ к координатам точки на чтение. Класс Point с закрытыми данными полностью бесполезен.